# TableViewCell height incorrect in iOS 8 with appearance proxies

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, uiappearance

In iOS 8 our table view cells are first displaying with the height from the xib file rather than with the height resulting after the appearance proxies are applied. For example, the fonts from the appearance proxy are present, but the label height is taken from the xib file. When the view is scrolled off and back on, the height is correct. This problem does not occur in iOS 9.

Any ideas how to address? We've tried `setNeedsLayout` followed by `layoutIfNeeded` and every other recommendation we've found on SO. We've also tried setting `estimatedRowHeight`.

The only workarounds we know of are to either ensure that in the xib file all the cell elements are the same height as their themed counterparts or to explicitly set the cell height through `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath`. Both of these cause the loss of much of the benefit of appearance proxies.

Comment: Have you tried [tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:)?

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yeah. See updated question.